# Are phrases or idioms like "state-of-the-art" appropriate for a formal technical recommendation report?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence, formality

I am supposed to write a technical recommendation report for my English class. My supposed client is a banking company and I would like to write a report on which endpoint protection software is the best choice for the company. This is a few sentences that I wrote:

> Moreover, new and more advanced complications within the security of the digital industry emerge every day. It is essential to ensure that the software is equipped with a state-of-the-art technology advanced enough to build a defense against these complications.

Does this paragraph sound formal enough? Or is there anyway it could be phrased better such that it would be more suitable to be read in a recommendation report?

I also wrote an alternative version of this, but I am not sure if it is any better.

> Moreover, with new and more advanced complications within the security of the digital industry emerging every day, it is essential for the software to be equipped with an ultramodern technology that could build a strong defense against more developed threats.

Which one sounds more suitable?

Comment: Neither *state-of-the-art* nor *ultramodern* are too informal for a technical report. However, both options smell of puffery. You should be able to recommend a solution without such overstated praise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "cutting edge" is more suitable here. It would outline the necessity of continuously upgraded software to withstand current security threats.